# Can anyone find a possible buffer overflow in this code snippet?

Tags: c

```
#define MAXSIZE 512
#define FILE "input.txt"

int check_file_size(int f) {
    struct stat s;
    fstat(f, &s);
    return s.st_size >= MAXSIZE;
}

void read_file() {
    char buffer[MAXSIZE];
    uint32_t bytes_to_read;

    int f = open(FILE, O_RDONLY);
    if(f == -1){
        ERROR_AND_EXIT("Found error with file");
    }
    printf("Please enter the number of bytes to read ");
    if(scanf("%u", &bytes_to_read) != 1)
    {
        ERROR_AND_EXIT("Invalid inputed bytes number");
    }
    ssize_t bytes_have_read = read(f, buffer, bytes_to_read);
    buffer[bytes_have_read] = 0;
}

int int main()
{
    read_file();
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone find a possible buffer overflow in this code snippet? For example, injecting malicious code through buffer overflow? I have enable the stack canaries mechanism, but I can't find if there is another possible buffer overflow. Thank you!

Comment: retagged as 'c' code, there is not a single c++ construct in that

Comment: ... and removed irrelevant "memory" tags. There is no memory management or potential memory leak whatsoever in this code.

Comment: Using `FILE`as a macro is a bad idea given that's the name of a standard type.

Comment: Also when you add that check watch out that with `buffer[bytes_have_read] = 0;` the `bytes_to_read` must be **less than** `MAXSIZE`. Perhaps OP overlooked that, and typed the same value instead of 1 less.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. The `ERROR_AND_EXIT` macro is missing backslashes and main is defined as `int int`. There's no `#include`s

Comment: @WeatherVane the file size is ensured to be less than `MAXSIZE` in `check_file_size`, so there shouldn't be any problems. But it's true that code like this is very error prone.

Comment: @Jabberwocky you've assumed that the file size doesn't change.  See my answer.

Comment: @PaulHankin that's true. I'll delete the comment and I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Actually, having answered this I feel bad because I think this isn't real code -- it's someone's specially-written vulnerable code for a security training course.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question by removing all relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's two potential ways to get a buffer over-run.

First, `fstat` can fail, and so your `check_file_size` may return 0 even if the file is too large (although it's almost certainly undefined behavior if you read the `stat` struct when `fstat` fails, so your code could do anything).

Then `bytes_to_read` can be inputted as an arbitrarily large value.

To get the buffer overflow, you need a file on which `fstat` can fail. Reading the man page suggest that a file with a size bigger than will fit into an `off_t` will do it.

A second (easier) way to get a buffer overflow is to make `input.txt` a named pipe, rather than a regular file. Then the `fstat` will succeed but produce a low `st_size`, but if you time it right you can push bytes into the pipe when you're reading. It's actually pretty easy because your code pauses to read `bytes_to_read`. Here's a repro:

Shell 1:

```
 $ mkfifo input.txt
 $ a.out
```

Shell 2:

```
 $ yes > input.txt
```

Shell 1:

```
 Please enter the number of bytes to read
 10000
```